# Different user agents on different websites

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, user-agent

I observe a very strange thing. I have two websites being opened on the same Lenovo tablet in the same browser in to different tabs. But I see different user agents. What may cause this?

UPDATE: I am connected via USB cable to the tablet in both cases.
[image]

Comment: I see that you have device emulation on. Is it possible you selected different devices?

Comment: @JosiahDaniels, plz see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that desktop mode checkbox was enabled on the site. With the checkbox device reports Linux OS instead of Android.

[image: desktop mode]